# Rearranging Array of WP_Post Objects and Arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, wordpress

After much time, I created a function that outputs an array of recent posts from any site in a WP multisite network.

Now, I'm having trouble with getting this array in a format to easily write out the posts.

**SOURCE ARRAY** (there are additional WP_Post Object elements, which I omitted for brevity).

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
       (
           [2013-07-15 04:19:59] => WP_Post Object
               (
                   [ID] => 1008
                   [post_author] => 52
                   [post_date] => 2013-07-15 04:19:59
                   [post_content] => This evening, we witnessed yet another travesty of justice in the ‘not guilty’ verdict on all counts against George Zimmerman the vigilante murderer of Trayvon Martin. 
                   [post_title] => Initial Statement on Verdict of George  Zimmerman Trial From Occu-Evolve
                   [guid] => http://occuevolve.web.net/?p=1
               )

           [2013-07-11 12:14:59] => WP_Post Object
               (
                   [ID] => 889
                   [post_author] => 1
                   [post_date] => 2013-07-11 12:14:59
                   [post_content] => Adam Weissman of OWS TradeJustice will be giving a talk on TPP (The Trans Pacific Partnership) on Sunday from 2-3 at Columbia.
                   [post_title] => This Sunday, Come to hear a talk on TPP – The Bankster’s Secret Plan to Escape Regulation and Kill Public Banks
                   [guid] => http://alternativebanking.web.net/?p=889
               )
           [2013-07-09 22:29:41] => WP_Post Object
               (
                   [ID] => 883
                   [post_author] => 1
                   [post_date] => 2013-07-09 22:29:41
                   [post_content] => It was just publicly and formally acknowledged, five years after AIG cost the US taxpayers billions of dollars that AIG is still a major problem.
                   [post_title] => AIG is still a threat to financial stability
                   [guid] => http://alternativebanking.web.net/?p=883
               )

           [2013-07-05 18:01:42] => WP_Post Object
               (
                   [ID] => 561
                   [post_author] => 12
                   [post_date] => 2013-07-05 18:01:42
                   [post_content] => 
                   [post_title] => The Good, The Bad, & The Ugly - Week of 7/1/2013
                   [guid] => http://occupythesec.web.net/?p=561
               )

           [2013-07-01 13:21:40] => WP_Post Object
               (
                   [ID] => 965
                   [post_author] => 51
                   [post_date] => 2013-07-01 13:21:40
                   [post_content] => Crossposted from mathbabe.org. Opinions expressed are those of Cathy O'Neil.
                   [post_title] => Payroll cards: "It costs too much to get my money" (#OWS)
                   [guid] => http://alternativebanking.web.net/?p=880
               )

           [2013-06-28 18:36:27] => WP_Post Object
               (
                   [ID] => 553
                   [post_author] => 50
                   [post_date] => 2013-06-28 18:36:27
                   [post_content] => 
                   [post_title] => The Good, The Bad, & The Ugly - Week of 6/24/2013
                   [guid] => http://occupythesec.web.net/?p=553
               )

           [2013-06-21 15:12:45] => WP_Post Object
               (
                   [ID] => 543
                   [post_author] => 50
                   [post_date] => 2013-06-21 15:12:45
                   [post_content] => 
                   [guid] => http://occupythesec.web.net/?p=543

               )

       )

   [1] => Array
       (
           [http://occuevolve.web.net/?p=1] => http://localhost/groups.occupy.net/web/occuevolve/2013/07/15/initial-statement-on-verdict-of-george-zimmerman-trial/
           [http://occupythesec.web.net/?p=561] => http://localhost/groups.occupy.net/web/occupythesec/2013/07/05/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly-week-of-712013/
           [http://occupythesec.web.net/?p=553] => http://localhost/groups.occupy.net/web/occupythesec/2013/06/28/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly-week-of-6242013/
           [http://alternativebanking.web.net/?p=889] => http://localhost/groups.occupy.net/web/altbanking/2013/07/this-sunday-come-to-hear-a-talk-on-tpp-the-banksters-secret-plan-to-escape-regulation-and-kill-public-banks/
           [http://alternativebanking.web.net/?p=883] => http://localhost/groups.occupy.net/web/altbanking/2013/07/aig-is-still-a-threat-to-financial-stability/
           [http://alternativebanking.web.net/?p=880] => http://localhost/groups.occupy.net/web/altbanking/2013/07/payroll-cards-it-costs-too-much-to-get-my-money-ows/
           [http://occupythesec.web.net/?p=543] => http://localhost/groups.occupy.net/web/occupythesec/2013/06/21/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly-week-of-61713/
       )

   [2] => Array
       (
           [http://occuevolve.web.net/?p=1] => 4
           [http://occupythesec.web.net/?p=561] => 3
           [http://occupythesec.web.net/?p=553] => 3
           [http://alternativebanking.web.net/?p=889] => 2
           [http://alternativebanking.web.net/?p=883] => 2
           [http://alternativebanking.web.net/?p=880] => 2
           [http://occupythesec.web.net/?p=543] => 3
       )

)
```

**DESIRED  RESULT**

```
Array
(
   [http://occuevolve.web.net/?p=1] => Array
       (
        [ID] => 1008
        [post_author] => 52
        [post_date] => 2013-07-15 04:19:59
            [post_content] => This evening, we witnessed yet another travesty of justice in the ‘not guilty’ verdict on all counts against George Zimmerman the vigilante murderer of Trayvon Martin.
        [post_title] => Initial Statement on Verdict of George  Zimmerman Trial From Occu-Evolve
        [post_url] => http://localhost/groups.occupy.net/web/occuevolve/2013/07/15/initial-statement-on-verdict-of-george-zimmerman-trial/
        [blog_id] => 4
       )

   [http://alternativebanking.web.net/?p=889] => Array
       (
        [ID] => 889
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2013-07-11 12:14:59
            [post_content] => Adam Weissman of OWS TradeJustice will be giving a talk on TPP (The Trans Pacific Partnership) on Sunday from 2-3 at Columbia.
        [post_title] => This Sunday, Come to hear a talk on TPP – The Bankster’s Secret Plan to Escape Regulation and Kill Public Banks
        [post_url] => http://localhost/groups.occupy.net/web/occupythesec/2013/07/05/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly-week-of-712013/
        [blog_id] => 3
       )

   [http://alternativebanking.web.net/?p=883] => Array
       (
        [ID] => 883
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2013-07-09 22:29:41
            [post_content] => It was just publicly and formally acknowledged, five years after AIG cost the US taxpayers billions of dollars that AIG is still a major problem.
        [post_title] => AIG is still a threat to financial stability
        [post_url] => http://localhost/groups.occupy.net/web/occupythesec/2013/06/28/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly-week-of-6242013/
        [blog_id] => 3
       )
 etc.....
)
```

*Note:*

- $array[1] contains the post_url
- $array[2] contains the blog_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do it for you, but I haven't tested it.

```
foreach ($array[0] as $wp_post){
  $desired_array[$wp_post->guid] = array(
     'ID' => $wp_post->ID,
     'post_author' => $wp_post->post_author,
     'post_date' => $wp_post->post_date,
     'post_content' => $wp_post->post_content,
     'post_title' => $wp_post->post_title,
     'post_url' => $array[1][$wp_post->guid],
     'blog_id' => $array[2][$wp_post->guid]
  );
}
```

UPDATE: If you want to keep the object then just do this (given that the object has properties `post_url` and `blog_id`):

```
foreach ($array[0] as $wp_post){
  $wp_post->post_url = $array[1][$wp_post->guid];
  $wp_post->blog_id= $array[2][$wp_post->guid]; 
  $desired_array[$wp_post->guid] = $wp_post;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your speedy reply! Your solution does work! However, it eliminates the object, which might be helpful for my task.A friend helped me with this and came up with this solution (see below).

(I'd upvote your reply, but I don't have a high enough rep yet).

Comment: No worries, but your desired result indicated that you wanted an array. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't clear. Your solution works; it gives the same result, but is much smaller.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me with this and came up with this solution.

```
$blog_posts = array();
foreach ($array[0] as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($array[1] as $guid => $post_url) {
        if ($value->guid == $guid) {
            $value->post_url = $post_url;
        }
    }
    foreach ($array[2] as $guid => $blog_id) {
        if ($value->guid == $guid) {
            $value->blog_id = $blog_id;
        }
    }
    $blog_posts[$value->guid] = $value;
}
```